# uiview render only specific area xcode (not by cropping)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, render, crop

I am now trying to render uiview. I can render the whole uiview correctly by something like this.

```
    [toBeRecorded.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

However, I would like to know to render only the specific area something like this (not by cropping ..but render only specific region). How should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the answer, I wrote this method, and works perfectly:

```
+ (UIImage*) screenShotTheArea:(CGRect)area inView:(UIView*)view{

        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(area.size.width, area.size.height), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
        else
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);

        CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextTranslateCTM(c, -area.origin.x, -area.origin.y);
        [view.layer renderInContext:c];
        UIImage* thePrintScreen = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return thePrintScreen;
    }
```